# Dependecy injection in asp.core: per-session, per-request lifetimes?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

Is it possible to inject a single instance of a service for user session?

So, If user logged in, it will re-use the same instance of a service across multiple requests? Rather than creating new instances per each HTTP request?

Comment: No, and there shouldn't be. This is an X/Y question, tell us why (you think) you need this,

Comment: @Henk Holterman e.g because all services depends on loggers and logger can depend on session. e.g. put each logged session to separate file (or use the same correlation token to reff all session messages together).

Comment: Yes, maybe. But  `Session-Token != Service-Instance`.  Correlation tokens can be arranged in middle ware.

Comment: Then you will need to include tokens into service interfaces. When In case of remote services it is predeterminated then in case of DI passed services you can initiate logger with token on session start and reuse logger around all components (managing DI through constructor "manually") hiding all details. This is about what the functional programmung is. Less OOP, more functional.

Comment: Thank for your comments guys, they helped me to clear my understanding of the DI.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. But it is not a problem really. Just do not use ASP DI for it - you are not obligated (and as node.js success shows: you do need many of those fancy features; ASP is overdesigned, all what you need to write the web backoffice - just HttpRequest, and output stream).

So:

1. less ASP DI (get from ASP DI only configuration, then do DI manually, as result  your components can leave "per session", "per request") - is OK.
2. less ASP Model Binding (better generate binding from metadata) - is OK.
3. less ASP/JSON.NET stream serializing (better generate serializers from metadata) - is OK
4. less razor (if you are still using it) - is OK.